# Cannot locate running X server

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I'm trying to run an X application over PuTTy from a Windows machine with Xming. The X server machine is Debian 8.1 and headless. I'm attempting to debug a separate issue with another application, but I'm encountering a very unusual problem: the X server appears to be running without showing up in any processes or log files. The symptoms:

- Basics like `gvim` and `xlogo` work as expected, which to me implies there's something somewhere that's serving up X
- `ps aux` reveals nothing that looks like an X server or window manager being run. Full process list: http://pastebin.com/GA8gEk0u
- `Xorg.0.log` and `Xorg.1.log` in `/var/log` are not being updated at all. Even manually starting X with `startx` does not update these logs.
- Explicitly calling `startx` works and runs without complaint. X functionality is unchanged compared to when it's not explicitly running in an active terminal window. It still doesn't log.
- `wmctrl -m` returns 
  `Cannot get window manager info properties. (_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK or _WIN_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK)`
- `service --status-all` reveals that the service `x11-common` is not running. `service x11-common start` returns `Failed to restart x11-common.service: Unit x11-common.service is masked.`. Unmasking this doesn't stick and make it runnable.
- Running a window manager like `i3` returns `ERROR: Another window manager seems to be running (X error 10)`

The problem persists through reboots. What problem am I having here? How can I identify where X is coming from?

Comment: If the Debian machine is headless, why do you expect it to have a running X server? It does not.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae OP says `startx` works so there is some semblance of `X` there :) Perhaps it is *headless* in the "has no monitor",  as OP wants to run applications remotely.

Comment: That's correct, it has no physical monitor but I'm trying to run an X application over PuTTy.